# Show Valid Values in Fluent Validation

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, fluentvalidation

I am using Fluent Validation and MVC filters to validate a request.  As part of the error, I'd like to show a list of valid values.  I'm not sure how to get the `ValidValues` property populated with a list of valid values the way that `FieldNam`e and `Message` are getting populated by the validation filter.

Currently the error message looks like this:

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "fieldName": "Make",
            "message": "Invalid Make"
        }
    ]
}
```

I'd like it to show something like this:

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "fieldName": "Make",
            "message": "Invalid Make",
            "validValues": ["Ford", "Honda"]
        }
    ]
}
```

My Error Model:

```
public class Error
{
    public string FieldName { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public string[] ValidValues { get; set; }
}
```

Validator:

```
RuleFor(car => car.Make)
    .Must(BeAValidMake)
    .WithMessage("Invalid Make.");
    //Add Valid values some how so they can be used by the validation filter to populate the error model.
```

Validation Filter:

```
public class ValidationFilter : IAsyncActionFilter
{
    public async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        if (!context.ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var errorsInModelState = context.ModelState
                .Where(x => x.Value.Errors.Count > 0)
                .ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value.Errors.Select(e => e.ErrorMessage)).ToArray();

            var errorResponse = new ErrorResponse();

            foreach (var error in errorsInModelState)
            {
                foreach (var subError in error.Value)
                {
                    var errorModel = new Error()
                    {
                        FieldName = error.Key,
                        Message = subError
                    };

                    errorResponse.Errors.Add(errorModel);
                }
            }

            context.Result = new BadRequestObjectResult(errorResponse);
            return;
        }

        await next();
    }
}
```

Comment: Check this state property of fluent validation, this might be useful https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/custom-state.html

Comment: @MuhammadKamranAslam this looks promising but do you know if this value is available from within the IAsyncActionFilter where the Error model is built?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't found any builtin property etc. that would be helpful but a Quick solution would be like this,

```
 public class InputModelValidator : AbstractValidator<InputModel>
{
    public InputModelValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.Name)
            .Length(1, 10);
        RuleFor(x => x.Email)
            .EmailAddress()
            .WithMessage("My Error Message %Split% Possible Values");
    }
}
```

And you action filter would look like this,

```
public class ValidationFilter : IAsyncActionFilter
{
    public async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        if (!context.ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var errorsInModelState = context.ModelState
                .Where(x => x.Value.Errors.Count > 0)
                .ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value.Errors.Select(e => e.ErrorMessage)).ToArray();

            var errorResponse = new ErrorResponse();

            foreach (var error in errorsInModelState)
            {
                foreach (var subError in error.Value)
                {
                    var errorModel = new Error()
                    {
                        FieldName = error.Key,
                        Message = subError.Split("%Split%")[0],
                        ValidValues = subError.Split("%Split%")[1],
                    };

                    errorResponse.Errors.Add(errorModel);
                }
            }

            context.Result = new BadRequestObjectResult(errorResponse);
            return;
        }

        await next();
    }
}
```

Example response

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "fieldName": "Email",
            "message": "My Error Message ",
            "validValues": " Possible Values"
        }
    ]
}
```